# I'm having trouble compiling my C++ files in Sublime Text 3 on my Mac

Tags: c++, sublimetext3, header-files

I'm working on C++ project for school, and I am not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm using Sublime Text 3 and I'm on a Mac. I have my project folder named Lab#2 and within the folder Lab#2 I have two more folders named Headers and Sources. Within the subfolder, **Headers** is the file Shapes.h and within the subfolder, **Sources** are the files main.cpp and ShapesImp.cpp. In the main.cpp and the ShapesImp.cpp I have included in the heading of the files #include "Shapes.h"

I created a new build system in Sublime Text that is supposed to be able to handle multiple files of C++. However, when I press Command + B in Sublime text, I get an error in both .cpp files that says, "*'Shapes.h' file not found.*" I'm assuming it's the sublime-build file that is incorrect. What do I need to do in order to compile and run this program correctly on my computer?

Here's what I have in the sublime-build file:

```
{
"shell_cmd": "g++ -std=c++11 -Wall \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\" && start cmd /k \"$file_base_name\"",
"working_dir": "${file_path}",
"selector": "source.cpp, source.cxx, source.cc, source.c++"
}
```

Comment: Side note: Consider using a portable (meta) build system like `cmake` rather than depending on a single editor or IDEs build system.

Comment: Your compile command can't handle include directories, and since you're only including `"Shapes.h"` and not `"Headers/Shapes.h"`, the compiler can't find your includes. Either qualify your `#include` directives, or add the compiler option to tell the compiler where to find Shapes.h. My preference is the latter.

Comment: Why are you including `start cmd /k \"$file_base_name\"` in your build system on a Mac? `start` and `cmd` are for Windows...